# Utilizar mi propia API en Electron

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, electron

Estoy intentando utilizar una API que cree yo mismo en Electron pero me sale el siguiente error:

```
(node:27034) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:27034) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:27034) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:27034) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

El código que tengo en Electron es el siguiente:

```
LogIn = (user) => {
    console.log(user)
    const xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/auth/login');
    xmlHttp.send(user)
    console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
}
```

Comment: ¿Para qué el `async` si no usas `await`? ¿Si vas a usar la forma síncrona de `XMLHttpRequest`, te hace falta especificarlo: _xmlHttp.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/auth/login', **false**);_, luego necesitas comprobar el estado de la solicitud: *if(xmlHttp.status == 200) { <aqui trabajas con la respuesta>}*. Por último, si usas `Electron`, yo recomendaría usar [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) en vez de `xmlHttpRequest`. Saludos

Comment: Hola disculpa el async ahora lo corregí no iba, utilice fetch pero sigue con el mismo error

Comment: Falta más contexto. Habría que ver cómo usas tu función. Y si realmente es tu función `LogIn` la que da problemas.